# Is there any alternative solution when the return value of Future.get() is too large?

Tags: java, future, scheduledexecutorservice

I get a large ScheduledFuture data as the return of Future.get(). I believe ScheduledFuture can only retrieve the return when get() is done.
So it will always generate a "java.util.concurrent.executionexception java.lang.outofmemoryerror java heap space" error on my machine.

Is there any alternative solution that I could split my return into parts when I'm using a scheduleExecutorService? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have your task save the result to disk, and have the `get()` method return the `File` to which the result was written.

Note that serialisation won't help you avoid memory issues, because you want to avoid creating the whole result in memory in the first place (passing it back doesn't use more memory).

You'll want to use a "streaming" approach, where small parts of the data are written to disk as soon as they are created.

Similarly, the user of the result should stream the data in, process small parts in memory, then discard the part (dereference it), before reading more in.

You may also consider using using a temporary file for convenience:

```
File file = File.createTempFile("foo", "dat");
file.deleteOnExit(); // optional, but safer
```